# Time Complexity for Array.copyOf()

Tags: java, arrays, big-o

I have a program that uses an array if integers to behave like a Stack of Integers. However, with an array, there must be a defined number of elements. When the user calls a method such as push() and that goes over the initial number of arrays, I must allocate everything from the original into the updated array and resize it.

If I have:

```
    int[] data = new int[100];
```

and the user calls push(), it would resize when necessary.

```
    public int push(int item) {
        if (size + 1 > data.length) { // O(n) solution
            data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length * 2 + 1); // double array size
        }
        data[size] = item; // size is elements from 0 to size that matter(as a stack)
        size++;
        return item;
    }
```

However, I am wondering: What the runtime complexity for Arrays.copyOf()? My tests seems to indicate somewhere between O(n) and O(constant), but I'm still not sure. If it isn't O(constant), is there a new way to resize the array while keeping a O(constant) runtime for this method?

Comment: Check out System.arrayCopy, it will be faster.

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is that while, copying may occasionally take place, it being a rare event will have a different amortized runtime than the actual time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of Array.copyOf is `O(n)`. 
Internally it uses `System.arraycopy` whose complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Isn't O(n) pretty much the same as O(length) since n is the number of elements in the array?

Comment: If that's the case, then there pretty much is no way to increase the array size while keeping an O(constant) runtime. I guess I will have to throw an IllegalStateException("exceeds list capacity") and then have a separate constructor for that class that will let the user define the size of the array from the start.

Comment: If you only need stack push/pop you could use a linked list to avoid the cost of size expansion.